# How to include menu

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, include

I'm trying to include my menu.php in many html files.
I followed instructions online, but can't display menu

this is my menu file

```
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="products.php">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
```

and this is how i try to include it in files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<?php include "includes/menu.php"; ?>  // OR   <ul id="navigation"><?php include("includes/menu.php"); ?></ul>
<p>Some text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Something doesn't work as I either get no menu bar or get just code written in a file.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is the file you are including it in a `.php` file or a `.html` file?

Comment: look into source code of your browser.... what happens ... post error or notice warnings here to help you .... p.s. use require_once instead of inlucde

Comment: Is your `index.php` file and `includes` dir at same level ?

Comment: both files are php, paths seem ok, same level

Comment: source code is the same as test file, has include statement, doesn't include code. Nothing changes if i use require

Comment: Is this on localhost or on a web server? Are you sure that PHP is working at all? You could put `phpinfo();` into the test file just to check...

Comment: this was it :( i converted some html files for an access help project to a nicer/newer look with menus, put them outside of access, but forgot to send them to loacalhost. Was working in netbeans so i never thought about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either way (with or without parenthesis) is okay - but make sure your path is correct -

if you use `require` - it'll fire an error, and if error reporting is turned on, you'll be able to see the full path that it is trying to include your `menu.php` from -

Otherwise, it is generally a good rule of thumb to include the full path:

`include "/absolute/path/to/includes/menu.php";`

Comment: <!--?php require - it's like this if i inspect the element

Comment: Looks like the server is editing out your PHP tags. Take a look at this question: [Why are my php tags converted to html comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828163/why-are-my-php-tags-converted-to-html-comments) Not the accepted answer, though, the one with 4 upvotes.