# .innerHTML to echo PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, dom, innerhtml

When i try to set my `<span>` to PHP variable, it sends it commented. The file is saved as .php and is served by apache2.4 from localhost

```
document.getElementById('displayName').innerHTML = " <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>";
```

This is what i see in browser when inspecting:

```
<!--?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?-->
```

Comment: Take a look at this post. Seems the same problem you have and it is solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828163/why-are-my-php-tags-converted-to-html-comments . Hopes this helps

Comment: try removing the quotation marks because that implies a string, or use the single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run PHP code with JavaScript. When the user receives the page, the server will have evaluated and run all PHP code, and taken it out.