# How can I run php on html pages using php 7.3

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am successfully using php code on html pages on php 7.2. My server php was recently upgraded to 7.3 and now the php doesnt work. The browser comments out any php code like this `<!--?php include("footer.php"); ?-->` In the htaccess file I am using `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php73 .php .php5 .html .htm` but this doesnt work. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Commenting out the PHP code is not a side effect of an upgrade to PHP 7.3. Are you using a hosting company? Ask them what they've done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828163/why-are-my-php-tags-converted-to-html-comments Might have some information. Do regular PHP files work?

Comment: yes regular php files work

Comment: Is this your server? How is PHP installed?